# Issue with shared KubernetesClient across Quarkus tests using TestContainers and K3s

Tags: kotlin, kubernetes, quarkus, testcontainers, k3s

**EDIT:** moved Issue to top.

I'm currently testing a Quarkus application that communicates with resources in a Kubernetes cluster. My app has controllers exposing REST endpoints, which utilize the KubernetesClient to interact with the cluster.

**Issue**

For each test method, the same client is shared. This leads to issues since the client gets closed in the controller logic. Meaning after the first test method, the subsequent interactions with the client will fail, because it gets closed.

My test environment is set up with TestContainers and K3s.
And inspired by: https://www.atomicjar.com/2023/09/testcontainers-the-simplest-way-to-test-kubernetes-operators/, I've implemented K3sResource for TestContainers lifecycle management.

Here's a brief overview:

**Application Code**

```
@ApplicationScoped
class ClientFactory {
    @Inject
    lateinit var client: KubernetesClient

    fun createClient(namespace: String): NamespacedKubernetesClient {
        return client.adapt(NamespacedKubernetesClient::class.java).inNamespace(namespace)
    }
}
```

**Controller Logic**

```kotlin
@Path("/namespaces/{namespace}/foo")
class FooController {
    @Inject
    lateinit var kubernetesClientFactory: KubernetesClientFactory

    @GET
    fun foo(@RestPath namespace: String): RestResponse<String> =
        runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
            kubernetesClientFactory.createClient(namespace).use {
                // ... logic
            }
        }
}
```

**Test Code** Two test classes (Test1, Test2) both inject KubernetesClient and make REST calls.

```
@QuarkusTest
@QuarkusTestResource(K3sResource::class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class Test1 {
    @Inject
    lateinit var client: KubernetesClient

    @Test
    fun testFoo() {
        RestAssured
            .`when`().get("/namespaces/$namespace/foo")
            .then().statusCode(200)
            .body(containsString("someExpectedString"))
    }

    @Test
    fun anotherTest() {
        // test logic
    }
}
```

How I ensure to use K3s:

```
@Alternative
@Priority(1)
@Singleton
class K3sConfigProducer : KubernetesConfigProducer() {
    // injects the kubeConfigYaml set in the K3sResource
    @ConfigProperty(name = "kubeConfigYaml")
    var kubeConfigYaml: String? = null

    @Singleton
    @Produces
    fun config(buildConfig: KubernetesClientBuildConfig?, tlsConfig: TlsConfig?): Config {
        return Config.fromKubeconfig(kubeConfigYaml)
    }
}

class K3sResource : QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {

    private var k3sContainer: K3sContainer = K3sContainer(DockerImageName.parse("rancher/k3s:v1.24.12-k3s1"))

    override fun start(): Map<String, String> {
        k3sContainer.start()
        return Collections.singletonMap("kubeConfigYaml", k3sContainer.kubeConfigYaml)
    }

    override fun stop() {
        k3sContainer.stop()
    }
}
```

Although I attempted to produce a new client for each test method with a `KubernetesClientProducer` like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
class KubernetesClientProducer {

    @Inject
    lateinit var config: Config

    @Produces
    @Dependent
    fun produceKubernetesClient(): KubernetesClient {
        val client = KubernetesClientBuilder().withConfig(config).build()
        println("Producing client: ${client.hashCode()}")
        return client
    }
}
```

it doesn't solve the issue. The `KubernetesClientFactory` in the app code still utilizes the same client across different tests. However, it will produce a different one for each test method.

Has anyone encountered a similar challenge integrating Quarkus, TestContainers, and K3s? Any insights or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to address this:

**1. Producer Class**
Use the producer class from my original question. To be more precise, annotating it with `@ApplicationScoped` will ensure that the class is instantiated only once. Then marking the producer method with `@Dependent` combined with the fact that our test classes are annotated with @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_METHOD) will ensure a new client is created for every test method.
So to re-iterate:

```
@ApplicationScoped
class KubernetesClientProducer {

    @Inject
    lateinit var config: Config

    @Produces
    @Dependent
    fun produceKubernetesClient(): KubernetesClient {
        return KubernetesClientBuilder().withConfig(config).build()
    }
}
```

**2. Inject factory and override field in test classes**
By injecting the `KubernetesClientFactory` into the test class, we can  override the client field and make sure it uses that object in the controller/other methods.

```
// ... other annotations
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_METHOD)
class Test1 {
    @Inject
    lateinit var client: KubernetesClient

    @Inject
    lateinit var factory: KubernetesClientFactory

    @BeforeEach
    fun beforeEach() {
        // setup 
        factory.client = client
    }
}
```